# Current Time Not working in WPF DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I'm making a DLL in WPF, C# and I'm using it in VC++.

In that DLL I have one textblock to display current time, and when I run the WPF application as a Windows application it shows current time correctly and also updated with new timings.

But when I use it as Dll in VC++ applcation, the current time is not getting updated. It shows the time when the applcaiton is loaded, that's all.

It's not get updated.

Code:

```
public Button()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
            DataContext = DateTime.Now.ToString("g");                      

        }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,6,211,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats my mistake.
I didnt properly build the solution.
Now its working.